# Obtaining only numeric output from viewFinancials without additional text

Tags: r, quantmod

I calculated dividend yield of Microsoft the following way:

```
# load financial data for MSFT
library(quantmod)
getFinancials('MSFT')

# calculate dividend yield for MSFT
as.numeric(first(-viewFinancials(MSFT.f, type='CF', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Cash Dividends Paid',]/viewFinancials(MSFT.f, type='BS', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Common Shares Outstanding',]))
```

Here is the output

```
Annual Cash Flow Statement for MSFT
Annual Balance Sheet for MSFT
[1] 1.40958
```

How is it possible to have only the numeric output `1.40958` without the additional text `Annual Cash Flow Statement for MSFT` and `Annual Balance Sheet for MSFT`? Is there a way to suppress those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two strings, "Annual Cash Flow Statement for MSFT" and "Annual Balance Sheet for MSFT" are messages from `viewFinancials`. They are not attached to the result in any way.

```
R> dy <- as.numeric(first(-viewFinancials(MSFT.f, type='CF', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Cash Dividends Paid',]/viewFinancials(MSFT.f, type='BS', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Common Shares Outstanding',]))
Annual Cash Flow Statement for MSFT
Annual Balance Sheet for MSFT
R> dy
[1] 1.40958
```

If you want to squelch the messages, use `suppressMessages()`.

```
R> suppressMessages(dy <- as.numeric(first(-viewFinancials(MSFT.f, type='CF', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Cash Dividends Paid',]/viewFinancials(MSFT.f, type='BS', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Common Shares Outstanding',])))
R> dy
[1] 1.40958
R>
```

Comment: yes, but it is part of a function that I wrote and use on multiple stock names at once, and it keeps putting out these message strings that is really annoying. Is there a way to silence it?

Comment: Use `?suppressMessages`